# MySQL not recognizing column name prefixed with table name

Tags: mysql

I am trying to reference a column name by prefixing it with the table name using the following query:

```
SELECT Employees.employee_id
FROM Employees
FULL JOIN Salaries on Employees.employee_id = Salaries.employee_id
```

I am getting an error that says "Unknown column 'Employees.employee_id' in 'field list'" even though employee_id is a column in Employees.
The full table schema is:

Table: Employees
| Column Name | Type    |
|:------------|:--------|
| employee_id | int     |
| name        | varchar |
employee_id is the primary key for this table.
Each row of this table indicates the name of the employee whose ID is employee_id.

Table: Salaries
| Column Name | Type    |
|:------------|:--------|
| employee_id | int     |
| salary      | int     |
employee_id is the primary key for this table.
Each row of this table indicates the salary of the employee whose ID is employee_id.

Why is it giving this error and how do I fix this?

Comment: MySQL does not support FULL JOIN, that's why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN instead of a FULL JOIN

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading and caused by FULL JOIN , full join does not exist in mysql see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8805879fb5cbe99514e65be464980a18. I am not going to suggest a fix since you haven't said what you are trying to achieve but if you search for mysql full join there are lots of suggestions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar experience. My query was

```
SELECT COALESCE(Calendar.cancel_policy_id, Villa.cancel_policy_id) AS policy_id
                    FROM    Calendar
                    JOIN    Villa ON Calendar.villa_id = Villa.villa_id
                    WHERE   Calendar.villa_id = :villa_id AND 
                            date >= :starts AND 
                            date < :ends
```

I got the same unknown column error. After trying a LOT of different options it turned out that only the Calendar table exhibited this error. So I checked the indexes and sure enough, the index was marked 'UNIQUE' and it shouldn't have been. Changed the index to 'INDEX' and the problem went away. Hope this helps.